# Editing excel file stored in Azure Storage using Azure Functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am running an Azure Function (PowerShell Core) and trying to create a new row with the values. I have loaded the ImportExcel module. But I am not sure what is the right way to reference the Excel. It is having an error that the file does not exists. Any ideas? Thanks.

Note: I don't have to use Powershell. Let me know if there are other ways as well

```
using namespace System.Net

param($Request)

$type = $Request.Body.type
$name = $Request.Body.name
$value = $Request.Body.value

Import-Excel -Path https://xxxxxxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/test/table.xlsx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Setup the file you want to read as input binding in the `host.json` like:**

```
 {
      "name": "myOutputBlob",
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "output/data.txt",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
      "direction": "out"
    }
```

- Connection `AzureWebJobsStorage` should contain the Azure Storage Account connection string in `local.settings.json`  if you're running the function locally.
- Path value should be like `container/filename.file-extension`.

**Push the data from your function code to this binding:**

```
Push-OutputBinding -Name myOutputBlob -Value 'my value'
```

**And the InputBlob should contain the blob data as an array of bytes:**

```
foreach ($value in $inputBlob) { ... }
```

Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-input?tabs=in-process,extensionv5&pivots=programming-language-powershell#example) for more information.