# Can you create Excel application objects inside Azure Functions?

Tags: excel, azure, powershell, azure-functions, cloud

Can you run (or import beforehand a module) to run a PS script in Azure Functions that manages imported Excel files in TEMP storage?

Think of running Excel processes in the background silently.

I.e. $objExcel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application

This would be using the Windows PowerShell Core offering.

Looking for any other workaround, if that is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

> Can you run (or import beforehand a module) to run a PS script in Azure Functions that manages imported Excel files in TEMP storage?

To import the excel file from a storage you have to set up the file from the temp storage. Use input binding to set the file in **host.json**. Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71928151/15997690)

After done the input binding of the temp storage excel file you can use the workbook object **`$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application`** to process the Excel operation in azure function.